# How to highlight font color of task item to red for overdue task

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, task-list, client-side-rendering

In SharePoint online task list, I am using below code to highlight a row in yellow if task is overdue:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
SP.SOD.executeFunc("clienttemplates.js", "SPClientTemplates", function() { 
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
        OnPostRender: function (ctx) {          
            // get today's date
            var today = new Date();
            // zero out the time portion so we will only compare days
            today.setHours(0,0,0,0);
            var rows = ctx.ListData.Row;
            for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                // get the date set in your date YourDateField
                var itemDate = new Date(rows[i]['DueDate']);
                var checkMark=rows[i]['Checkmark'];
                // zero out the time portion so we only compare days
                itemDate.setHours(0,0,0,0);
                var rowId = GenerateIIDForListItem(ctx, rows[i]);
                var row = document.getElementById(rowId);
                if (row!=null&&itemDate <= today&&checkMark=="No") {                
                    row.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
                    var itemId=rowId.split(',')[1];
                    var parentRowId=rowId.split(',')[0]+","+getParentTaskId(ctx.ListTitle,itemId)+","+rowId.split(',')[2];                  
                    var parentRow=document.getElementById(parentRowId);
                    parentRow.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';              
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
function doCollapseTaskList() {
    $(".ms-commentcollapse-iconouter > img").each(function(){
        $(this).click();
    });
}
$(function () {
      ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function () {
          if (typeof asyncDeltaManager != "undefined")
            asyncDeltaManager.add_endRequest(doCollapseTaskList);
          else doCollapseTaskList();
      }, "init.js");
});
function getParentTaskId(listTitle,taskId){
    var id=taskId;
    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('"+listTitle+"')/items("+taskId+")?$select=ParentID/Id&$expand=ParentID",
        method: "GET",
        async:false,
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: function(data){
            taskId=data.d.ParentID.Id;
        }
    });
    if(taskId!=undefined){
        return getParentTaskId(listTitle,taskId);
    }else{
        return id;
    }
}
</script>
```

Below is the image for your information.

In addition to background color, I would like to highlight the font color as well of text "Task Main' , Due Date value:1/16/2019, which property should I use? Any help is appreciated.

[image]

P.S: I got this answer from sp stack exchange only but not getting further response on that thread so had to post this as a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
row.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
parentRow.style.color = 'red';
```

After below line:

```
parentRow.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
```

**Update**:

try adding below code:

```
var jRow = $(row);
```

And add `red-color` class if task is overdue, inside `if (row!=null&&itemDate <= today&&checkMark=="No")` block:

```
jRow.addClass("red-color");
```

After this:

```
var row = document.getElementById(rowId);
```

Also add below CSS in your custom CSS file:

```
.red-color, .red-color > p, .red-color > span, .red-color > td, .red-color > a {
    color: red !important;
}
```

Only problem in this code is you need to add all elements in CSS selector as SharePoint list shows data in `table, td's` and inner elements like `span, a, p`, etc. inside `td`.

Comment: If it is not working then let me know. Also, as you are not sharepoint online are you comfortable with using modern experience? Because styling is more easy in modern experience using JSON formatting.

Comment: it does not work.

Comment: Also try adding `row.style.backgroundColor = 'red';`

Comment: Even if this is not working, then you can add class to your tr row using jquery's addClass() function and write css for that class using !important.

Comment: the alternative you suggested does not work as well, can you share snippet for jquery approach u mentioned.

Comment: you need add custom css in your code/page for that.

Comment: Well I am not looking apply to css for all tasks font color but just that are overdue. From CSS standpoint I understand we can override color by mentioning classes but I am not sure How it will be applicable to just the overdue ones, can you share snippet please if possible, thanks again.

Comment: the Jrow snippet does not work, also I do not have a css file as I did not want to apply red color in general but for overdue only.